# VirtualBox, Vagrant & Laravel Homestead "vagrant up" error

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I'm currently trying to switch back to Laravel Homestead after using Laragon for a while, after the release of Laravel 5.3. I've followed all of the steps on the [guide in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead), and watched several screencast tutorials but I get this error when running `vagrant up`:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "977385f5-4aa5-4def-be66-1741ac9b560b", "--type", "headless"]
```

> Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'homestead-7' has
>   terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code -1073741819
>   (0xc0000005).  More details may be available in
>   'C:\Users\\VirtualBox VMs\homestead-7\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'
>
> VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component
>   MachineWrap, interface IMachine

As it says in the error, [here](http://pastebin.com/usRfHnyK) is my `VBoxHardening.log`

Also, I have tried reinstalling VirtualBox and that didn't fix it.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Use this command and see the result: `vagrant box list`

Comment: make sure your combination of vagrant/virtualbox is compatible

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. the output of `vagrant box list` is `laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 0.5.0)`, and is there a way to find out which versions of Vagrant and VirtualBox are compatible?

Comment: you can look at https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md or indicate your version, others can tell you if they have issues with such combination

Comment: @Sean Whelan: Are you using macOSx?

Comment: @Sean Whelan: For Mac OS X 10.9.3 and Vagrant 1.6.3 and VirtualBox 4.3.6 this problem was fixed with restarting the VirtualBox, using `sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart`  Let me know if this works and also what happened after using this?

Comment: @Sean Whelan: Are you using windows-7/8??

Comment: @Hiren Gohel: Hi Hiren, really sorry, I never received your comments in an email. I'm afraid I'm not using Mac OSx,  I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: @Sean Whelan: It's ok, no problem. I'm just trying to solve your issue. Right now, i just post a answer for you. Let me know if that useful or not ok? Because i can't post it in comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this post hasn't had any activity in months, but I just wanted to update it as I found out what was causing the problem a few months ago. It was actually [MacType](https://github.com/snowie2000/mactype), a font smoother I was using. I uninstalled it, and it just worked, no problem at all.

Comment: Thank you, I just installed MacType today and had this exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your laptop and just see it's gives you that error? You just follow this steps:

```
1. Right click on "This PC" / "My Computer" on windows desktop
2. Select "Properties"
3. Go to "Advanced" tab
4. Click "Environment Variables..." at the bottom
5. Under System Variables click "New..."
6. Set "Variable name" to "VBOX_INSTALL_PATH"
7. Set "Variable value" to "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"
8. Select "OK" and close all the other settings windows
```

Hope this helps you!!:)

Comment: @Sean Whelan: Is this helps you?

Comment: Sadly not. The environment variable was already there. I tried deleting it and adding it again, but still getting the same error. :(

Comment: Ooops! Sorry, then i don't have any idea in win-10. But, If you are using MacOSX, then i definitely help you further.

Comment: @SeanWhelan Please give upvote if this steps works! Any other user may follow this if they get same issue!

Comment: Hi Hiren, unfortunately, your answer didn't work as it was MacType that was causing the issue, as stated above in the answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your kind reply!! You are right may be it's not work for mactype!. But i think for windows user, this works! Anyways, thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after updating Windows 10 and my Nvidia (and Geforce Experience) drivers.

I did a "vagrant box update", but still got the error.

I updated my virtualbox and vagrant said it couldn't use this version of virtualbox.

Then I downloaded the latest vagrant (1.8.6) and it solved the problem.

https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of the answers on this question or others in Stack Overflow helped me. Problem appeared to go away if I uninstalled virtualbox and reinstall. But then if I reboot the host machine, the issue came back and had to repeat. Very frustrating.

I came across [this post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=88480) and it turns out that **Trusteer Rapport** was causing the issue. No idea why, but it seems the problem came after an update in June 2018. I uninstalled Trusteer Rapport, reinstalled virtualbox and everything is working!